# SQL update query per entry

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wan't to update a column if a certain userid was found in a log for violations.

```
UPDATE 
USER_CHECK_LOGIN
SET 
CHECKLOGIN = 2
WHERE 
USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_ID = (SELECT NAME from XTREME.gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 WHERE GATENUM=150);
```

What this query does is, if a userid is found in the logs where the gatenum is 150, all users will be banned.

But I seem to get an error.

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =,     !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `=`, use `IN()` since the subquery is expected to return multiple rows.  Using `=` in comparison against a subquery return value assumes only one row with one column is returned.

```
USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_ID IN (SELECT NAME from XTREME.gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 WHERE GATENUM=150);
```

Comment: This query too banned all the accounts. O_O OMG.

Comment: (23520 row(s) affected)
Should only affect 1 because there is currently only 1 entry on the log_using_depot...

Comment: @user1553142 That is what your description says it should do, no?

Comment: @user1553142 Are you certain there is only one entry? Execute the subquery by itself.

Comment: All users that are found on the log_using_depot where the gatenum is 150.

Comment: Oh, it works now. Thanks. I saw the problem, when i run the subquery.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid a subquery entirely using join:

```
UPDATE UCL
SET 
CHECKLOGIN = 2
FROM
USER_CHECK_LOGIN UCL
JOIN
XTREME.gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 LUD
    ON LUD.NAME = UCL.USER_ID
WHERE 
LUD.GATENUM=150;
```

Answer (score 1):

USE `IN`

```
UPDATE 
USER_CHECK_LOGIN
SET 
CHECKLOGIN = 2
WHERE 
USER_CHECK_LOGIN.USER_ID IN (SELECT NAME from XTREME.gamelogs.dbo.LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 WHERE GATENUM=150);
```

Comment: Hello, but this query banned all the accounts O_O

Comment: (23520 row(s) affected)
should only affect 1. O_O

Comment: It does what you asked for: "What this query does is, if a userid is found in the logs where the gatenum is 150, **all users*** will be banned.". If that is what you want, then the inner select to LOG_USING_DEPOT201211 returns all userIds with a getnum of 150. Then you want to set the checklogin value of those users to 2, right?